# .htaccess redirect all pages except 1 to http from https

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have two websites, one that runs 99% as http (site A) and one that runs 100% as https (site B).

I want to create an htaccess file that redirects users that go from site B to site A without changing their URL from https: to http: automatically to switch to http:

What I have on site A is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sitehere.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Which works perfectly, except I have one page that I *do* want to serve as https: on site A.
How do I exclude this page from the above htaccess rule? (let's pretend I know the full path/file location that I want to exclude, and it's /news/)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it as a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sitehere.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you've put earlier and it didn't work. Turned out I was having a bit of a /facepalm moment. I was including this rule before the wordpress custom file-structure statement, so naturally, at that point the page wasn't called /news/ Thanks very much!